# Run Openshift pod as root user

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I am trying to install docker inside an openshift pod like below.

```
sh-4.2$ yum install docker
Loaded plugins: ovl, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
ovl: Error while doing RPMdb copy-up:
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/rpm/.dbenv.lock'
You need to be root to perform this command.
sh-4.2$ id
uid=1001(1001) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
sh-4.2$
```

Tried applying following
oc adm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid -z default

Could you please help.

Answer (score 7):

You should specify "0" using "runAsUser" as follows. Because "anyuid" is using UID which is configured when an image builds if you do not specify the UID in your container. I think your image is build with 1001 UID initially as far as I can see the result.

```
     containers:
     - name: YOURCONTAINERNAME
       :
       securityContext:
           runAsUser: 0
```

Comment: Thank you , i have added the above and see now whoami is root